# Ingesting Timestamp field from Oracle to HDFS using NIFI

Tags: oracle, hadoop, timestamp, unix-timestamp, apache-nifi

I am trying to insert a table from Oracle to HDFS using Nifi. The source table in Oracle has a `timestamp(6)` datatype field called `sd_timestamp`.
Nifi is having the following processor:

1. QueryDatabase:
   This queries the OracleDatabase.
2. CovertAVROSchema:
   This one has input and output schemas. Both input and output schemas have `sd_timestamp` datatype as String.
3. ConvertAvroToOrc
4. PutHDFS:
   The table that is created in Hive also has the datatype as string for `sd_timestamp`. When the ingestion is done and I do a `select *` from the destination hive table, I am getting `oracle.sql.timestamp@23aff4` as the value instead of the timestamp.

Please help.

Comment: Okay.. btw, do you want it to be saved as a String in the Hive external table as well or you're okay with it being a String?

Answer (score 2):

Here are details of what I did to get it working. Did not require the `ConvertAvroSchema` step.

**Oracle table**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  entry_name varchar(10),
  sd_timestamp timestamp(6)
);
```

**Populate some data**

```
insert into my_table values('e-1',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
insert into my_table values('e-2',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
insert into my_table values('e-3',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

**Verify data**

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
ENTRY_NAME   SD_TIMESTAMP
e-1          09-MAY-18 06.45.24.963327000 PM
e-2          09-MAY-18 06.45.39.291241000 PM
e-3          09-MAY-18 06.45.44.748736000 PM
```

**NiFi Flow**

Flow Design
[image]

QueryDatabaseTable configuration
[image]

ConvertAvroToOrc configuration
[image]

PutHDFS configuration
[image]

LogAttribute to see the hive.ddl attribute value
[image]

**Verify results on HDFS**

```
$ hadoop fs -ls /oracle-ingest
/oracle-ingest/50201861895275.orc
```

**Create Hive table to query data using the hive.ddl value and adding location to it**

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_oracle_table 
(
    ENTRY_NAME STRING, 
    SD_TIMESTAMP STRING
) 
STORED AS ORC 
LOCATION '/oracle-ingest';
```

**Query Hive table**

```
hive> select * from my_oracle_table;
e-1 2018-05-09 18:45:24.963327
e-2 2018-05-09 18:45:39.291241
e-3 2018-05-09 18:45:44.748736
```

Comment: This solution will work for a table just having string and timestamp fields but will give issues with int , long datatypes as those values will not be converted back to the Integer values and will remain as Strings only.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to resolve the error by adding the following java argument to the bootstrap.conf file present in Nifi/Conf directory

-Doracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant=true